# Power Query - Remove Consecutive Duplicates Only

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a dataset (Airport Location Codes)  e.g. London (LHR), Paris (CDG), Rome (FCO) etc on each row.

On some rows the entry might be London, London, London, Paris. which I planned to remove by clearing duplicates however on some instances I have genuine duplicates e.g. London, Paris London. Where I want to retain the final both London's because there was another location in between. If we consider Airport codes, the route might look like this -

LHR, LHR, CDG, FCO, FCO (Change to LHR-CDG-FCO) -

LHR, LHR, CDG, CDG, CDG, LHR (Change to LHR-CDG-LHR) What I was able to Achieve is Distinct List where it just returned LHR-CDG.

The number of times a code could appear is dynamic.

Is there function available in PowerQuery that could return this type of logic?

Sample data:

| ID | Route | Required Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LHR, LHR, CDG,CDG, FCO | LHR-CDG-FCO |
| 2 | AMS, AMS, LHR, CDG | AMS-LHR-CDG |
| 3 | AMS, AMS, LHR, AMS, AMS | AMS-LHR-AMS |
| 4 | CGN-CGN-AMS-AMS-AMS-CDG-CDG-AMS | CGN-AMS-CDG-AMS |
| 5 | CGN-CGN-CDG-CDG-CDG | CGN-CDG |

Comment: Can you post a full sample and expected out?

Comment: @David Added an example table for route & required result if that is clear?

Comment: You have 2 solutions to choose from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using `List.Accumulate` and `List.Last`, paste this formula into a New Custom Column:

```
Text.Combine(
    List.Transform(
        List.Accumulate(
            Text.SplitAny([Route], ",-") /* Will split given column on any of the listed delimiters in 2nd argument */
            , {}, (state,current) => 
            if List.Last(state) <> Text.Trim(current) 
            then List.Combine({state, {Text.Trim(current)}}) 
            else state 
         ), 
        Text.From
    ), "-" /* Delimiter for output column */
)
```

This function does the following:

- Splits your text column into a list using the separators given in `List.SplitAny`
- Using an empty list as a baseline in `List.Accumulate`, it loops over your split column list and checks how the last element of the list compares to the current (trimmed, to avoid leading/trailing spaces) loop value
- If the current loop value is the same as the last element of the list, the element is skipped
- If the current loop value is NOT the same as the last element, we add it to the state using `List.Combine`
- Finally, after the loop has finished, we use `Text.Combine` with a set delimiter to combine the result from `List.Accumulate` into a text string

While it is an advanced function, I am quite happy with it!

Comment: I like that - I was playing around with adding index columns and joining.  Would work for a single column. :)  Still so much to learn with M.

Comment: Nice. List.Accumulate always makes my head spin so I went with a recursive option.

Comment: I figured this looked like a nice use-case for practicing `List.Accumulate` - looping of any kind in M seems wrong, but here we are!

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. Can I ask is it possible to do this with 2 columns, turn them into a list then remove the row if only certain criteria is met? 
E.g. LHR1, LHR2, CDG1, CDG2, LHR1 would only check for the first 3 CHAR, So Result would be LHR1-CDG1-LHR1.  Retaining the 4 character code only

Comment: I can’t see why not, it only requires some adjustments in the code above. The input to `List.Accumulate` then needs to get a combined list of both columns, and the comparison needs to account for the first letters only using something along the lines of `Text.StartsWith(List.Last(state)), Text.Start(current, 3)` .

Comment: I screwed up the parentheses, but I’m sure you get the gist of it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative using a custom function.

[image]

```
(values as text, index as number) as text => let
    array = Text.Split(values, ","),
    arrayLength = List.Count(array) - 1,
    same = if array{index}=array{1+index} then true else false,
    compare = if array{index}=array{1+index} then List.RemoveRange(array,index,1) else array,
    result = if index < arrayLength then @collapse(Text.Combine (compare,","), if same = true then index else index+1) else values

in result
```

The function is named collapse.